# How to eliminate redundancy using a function (def)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a currency converter and I've pretty much finished the program. However, I am trying to eliminate redundancy by implementing a function or a define block. I've tried a number of things but it does not seem to be working.

My current code is like this:

```
EUR = 0.83

EGY = 16.22

def currency_converter():
  money = total_value
  new_value = 0
  if currency == 1:
    new_value = money*EUR_CON
    print("Your total is " + "$" + str(money) + " US Dollars  which is " + "e£ " + str(new_value) + " European Euros.")
  elif currency == 2:
    new_value = money*EGY_CON
    print("Your total is " + "$" + str(money) + " US Dollars  which is " + "e£ " + str(new_value) + " Egyptian Pounds.")
```

I want to essentially make the clause under the `if`/`elif` block a function. I've tried doing this:

```
def conversion(EUR_CON,GDP_CON, BRL_CON, EGY_CON, YEN_CON):
  new_value = money*conversion()
  print("Your total is " + "$" + str(money) + " US Dollars  which is " + str(new_value)+ str(conversion)

if currency == 1:
    conversion(EURO_CON)
```

But it's not working. Can someone help?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Ok @Barmar  sorry about that.

Comment: The `conversion` function 1) is recursive and has no escape path, and 2) has many parameters which are not being provided by either caller.

Comment: Assuming you always start from the same currency and only want it to be converted to single other, I would put a single argument for a function, based on users response for which he wants to use. Then use apropriate value based on that response. Here you are requiring multiple arguments for a function, but declared only one when calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your conversion rates into a list or dictionary, so you don't need all those `if` statements.

You don't need so many parameters to the function. Just the currency you're converting to and the amount. The function can then look up all the information related to the currency parameter.

```
conversion_data = {
    'EUR': {'rate': 0.83, 'symbol': '€', 'name': 'European Euros'},
    'EGY': {'rate': 16.22, 'symbol': '£', 'name': 'Egyptian Pounds'},
    ...
}

def conversion(currency, dollars):
    new_value = dollars * conversion_data[currency]['rate']
    return f"Your total is ${dollars} US dollars which is {conversion_data[currency]['symbol']}{new_value} {conversion_data[currency]['name']}."

print(conversion('EUR', 5))
```

Comment: when i call the function conversion() what do I put within the parentheses? I put EUR, 0.83 but it is giving me an error message.

Comment: I showed an example

Comment: The first argument must be a string in quotes. The second is the amount of dollars,

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to make a mapping or `enum` that ties the type of conversion to the associated parameters (in this case, the multiplier and the string name of the target currency). For example, with `enum`:

```
from enum import Enum

class Currency(Enum):
    EUR = 0.83, "European Euros"
    EGY = 16.22, "Egyptian Pounds"

def currency_converter(target_currency):
    multiplier, name = target_currency.value  # Retrieve value of enum and unpack parts for use
    new_value = money * multiplier
    print(f"Your total is ${money} US Dollars which is {new_value} {name}")
```

which then allows you to use it with just:

```
currency_converter(Currency.EUR)  # Convert to euros
```

To be clear: Using a `dict` for a similar purpose is perfectly fine as well. Enums mostly just emphasize that there are a fixed, known set of possible conversions, where `dict`s don't have that idea baked in as thoroughly (adding and removing keys is always a possibility).

I'll note that in real code, functions generally shouldn't rely on receiving non-constant information from globals, nor should they `print` the results (`return`ing them allows the caller to `print`, or not `print`, as they choose) so a better design would be something like:

```
def convert_usd_to_currency(target_currency, money):
    multiplier, _ = target_currency.value  # Retrieve value of enum and unpack parts for use
    return money * multiplier
```

possibly with a helper that does the `print`ing (if you really have many places that need to format it the same way):

```
def print_converted_currency(currency, money):
    new_value = convert_usd_to_currency(currency, money)
    print(f"Your total is ${money} US Dollars which is {new_value} {currency.name}")
```

I'll admit to a failure of imagination here; I almost never see a need to factor out the output code itself (each location prints different things based on need), so I'd probably just inline that work in the one place that actually `print`s it (as opposed to potentially many places that need to perform the conversion).